# Php does not load a new ini file (xdebug)

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant, xdebug

During vagrant provision I am copying my xdebug.ini file like this:

```
 cp "/srv/config/php-config/xdebug.ini" "/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini"
```

but after provisioning is done I do not see it symlinked to.

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/
```

Tried to do this manually, but it does not work. It even looks differently:

[image: Directory listing]

Tried to restart my php-fpm service a couple of times, but it just does not apply. When looking at phpinfo() xdebug is not loaded.

Comment: Yes, ubuntu linux

Comment: `mods-available` is a particularity of Debian-based distros. I presume you're using one... :-? Are you trying to configure command-line interface (as your screenshot suggests) or web based PHP (as your reference to php-fpm suggests)?

Comment: I am trying to apply xdebug.ini file to php and make it load it. I am doing this through terminal.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself properly. Do you plan to use PHP to run command-line scripts (e.g. typing stuff in the console) or you want to build web sites to be used through a browser like Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: to build web sites to be used through a browser like Firefox or Chrome

Comment: I figured out. I just needed to run phpenmod xdebug